# Nightwatch - Parameters passed to env to run tests in parallel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, nightwatch.js

I'm running tests using tasks in VS Code and I've stacked with problem of parallel launching tests.

I want to pass two environments to env variable in order to start tests. With one environment, everything works perfect, but if I pass several -all tests start with default configuration in 4 threads.

Example:

```
var nightwatchOptions = {
    config: './dist/dev/specs/e2e/nightwatch/nightwatch.json',
    env: ['firefox', 'chrome']   ---> this one doesn't work
};
```

I also tried to pass it like that: `env: 'firefox,chrome'` and like that `['firefox,chrome']` - first one hangs, second one - default configuration.
`env: 'chrome'` ---> this one works perfect.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've just figured out how to avoid this issue. I decided to start it with the help of child_process of nodejs:

```
nightwatchOptions = ['node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js',
    '-c',
    'path to config'];

var tests = child_process.spawn('node', nightwatchOptions, {
    stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

And I've added test_workers to nightwatch config. Now it works fine for me.